# Determine Property Value

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have an existing Window Forms application. The application has a property grid. The values of the properties are set by the user at runtime. What I would like to do is determine from code the current value of any given property. I have had partial success. I am able to get the Category as well as the property name information. I am having difficulty getting the current value of the properties as set by the user, as well as two other related questions.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
 // ICustomTypeDescriptor Interface Implementation
 public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(GetType());
 }

 public string GetClassName()
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetClassName(GetType());
 }

 public string GetComponentName()
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetComponentName(GetType());
 }

 public TypeConverter GetConverter()
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(GetType());
 }

 public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultEvent(GetType());
 }

 public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetDefaultProperty(GetType());
 }

 public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetEditor(GetType(), editorBaseType);
 }

 public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(GetType(), attributes);
 }

 public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetEvents(GetType());
 }

 public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
 {
      // ... This returns a list of properties.
      PropertyDescriptorCollection pdc = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType(), attributes);
      PropertyDescriptor[] arr = new PropertyDescriptor[pdc.Count];
      pdc.CopyTo(arr, 0);
      PropertyDescriptorCollection propertyCollection = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(arr);

      ModifyProperties(propertyCollection); // modifies which properties are visible

      // temporary code to get the program to print out the properties
foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in propertyCollection)
{
           Print("input category = "+pd.Category);
           Print("input display name = "+pd.DisplayName);
           Print("input name = "+pd.Name);
        // Print("input value = "+pd.GetValue(Input).ToString()); <--- Does NOT work
}

return propertyCollection;
 }

 public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
 {
      return TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(GetType());
 }

 public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
 {
      return this;
 }
```

My questions are:

1. How can I get the values of the properties? For example, I have a property aspect ratio. Its display name is Aspect Ratio and its name is aspectRatio. Its value is 5. How can I retieve this via code at runtime?
2. How can I order the properties. I have tried to use the above approach to ordering the properties but the ordering failed. I am not sure how best to proceed.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: May be I missing stuff in this new fangled approach from basic reflection, but seeing as there's no instance in your code, how can it have a value? You want the PropertyDescriptionCollection for an object, not it's type, surely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this

```
foreach (PropertyDescriptor pd in propertyCollection)
{
     Print("input category = "+pd.Category);
     Print("input display name = "+pd.DisplayName);
     Print("input name = "+pd.Name);
     Print("input value = " + pd.GetValue(GetPropertyOwner(pd)));   
}
```

If you have custom objects you want to get a nice string from you could add a helper method like below:

```
    private string GetPropertyValue(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        var property = GetPropertyOwner(pd);
        if (property is CustomObject)
        {
            var dataSeries = property as CustomObject;
            // This will return a string of the list contents ("One, Two, Three")
            return string.Join(",", dataSeries.ListProperty.ToArray());

        }
        else if (property is ....)
        {
            return somthing else
        }
        return property.ToString();
    }
```

Demo class:

```
public class CustomObject
{
    private List<string> _listProperty = new List<string>(new string[]{"One","Two","Three"});
    public List<string> ListProperty
    {
        get { return _listProperty; }
        set { _listProperty = value; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Edited to makr use of your "GetPropertyOwner" function.

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked extremely well on almost all the properties. One of my properties, however, is a data series and in that case it did not work. It did not give me the name of the series input by the user. It simply returned the string DataSeriesHelper. Any suggestions? Also, any suggestions re custom ordering the properties? Thank you very much once again.

Comment: GetValue returns the Value of the object, not all objects have a pretty .ToString(), if these are Custom objects you can override .ToString() to return what you want. Or you could add a helper method to make a nice string for Properties like Lists,Arrays etc

Comment: You have been extremely helpful. Thank you very much. Can you please give me an idea of how to do this. The input series property currently shows TF 12-12 (5 Min) but the value returned is DataSeriesHelper. Iam not sure how to retieve this from the value returned.